# Compare numbers to cards numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, compare, flip

I'm writing a simple html game. I want to compare the red cards' numbers to random numbers. If any one of random numbers equal to red cards' numbers, then dynamically add "*BINGO*" text to red square's `back` class when user flip red cards. It's like bingo game, user don't know which cards have "*BINGO*" strings before they flip red cards. I have problem with comparing array numbers to `front` class numbers and dynamically add "*BINGO*" string to red cards. Can somebody help please?

JSFIDDLE is here: http://jsfiddle.net/7emqLztp/28/

```js
$(".treasure").flip();

var howMany = 3;
        var min = 2;
        var max = 5;
        var a = new Array();
        while (a.length < howMany) {
            var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + 0.5) + min;
            if (a.indexOf(n) == -1) {
                a.push(n);
            }
        }

$("#button").click(function () {
    $('.num').text(a)
  });
```

```css
.table 
{
   display: table;
   border-collapse:separate;
   /*border-spacing: 5px;*/
   /*border: 1px solid #fff;*/
}

.table-row 
{
  display: table-row;
}

.table-cell 
{
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  border: 0.5px solid #231f20;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
        
.treasure 
{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/nnattawat/flip/master/dist/jquery.flip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/nnattawat/flip/master/dist/jquery.flip.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div class="table">
        <div class="table-row">
            <div class="table-cell">
                1
            </div>
            <div class="table-cell treasure">
              <div class="front">2</div>
              <div class="back"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="table-cell treasure">
                <div class="front">3</div>
                <div class="back"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="table-cell treasure">
                <div class="front">4</div>
                <div class="back"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="table-cell treasure">
                <div class="front">5</div>
                <div class="back"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="table-cell">
                6
            </div>
        </div>
</div>

<button id="button">Random Num</button>
<div class="num"></div>
```

Comment: Do you have problems with implementation or the idea how to do it?

Comment: @Papi Hi, my problem is how to implement about comparing div numbers to random array numbers, and after compare numbers I want to add "BINGO" to red cards if div numbers equal to array numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at this updated code. I'm pretty sure this is working.

```js
$(".treasure").flip().find(".back").text("-")
var cardCount = 3;
var bingoCards = [];

do {
  let n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 2;
  if (bingoCards.indexOf(n) === -1) {
    bingoCards.push(n)
    let item = $(".treasure")[n-2];
    $(item).find(".back").text("BINGO")
  }
} while (bingoCards.length < cardCount)


$("#button").click(function() {
  $("#result").html(`The numbers are: <b>${bingoCards.join(", ")}</b>`)
});
```

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  border-collapse: separate;
  /*border-spacing: 5px;*/
  /*border: 1px solid #fff;*/
}

.table-row {
  display: table-row;
}

.table-cell {
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  border: 0.5px solid #231f20;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.treasure {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/nnattawat/flip/master/dist/jquery.flip.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/nnattawat/flip/master/dist/jquery.flip.min.js"></script>


<div class="table">
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">1</div>
    <div class="table-cell treasure">
      <div class="front">2</div><div class="back"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell treasure">
      <div class="front">3</div><div class="back"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell treasure">
      <div class="front">4</div><div class="back"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell treasure">
      <div class="front">5</div><div class="back"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">6</div>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="button">Random Numbers</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help! But I found some problem. Why the random numbers show "2,3,5" however when I flip the cards, the "BINGO" words showed on "2,3,4"? Not match to the random numbers

Comment: I have updated the code to make it a bit prettier. I'm glad I could help you.